# Trying to pull data from object based on extension's received from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to figure out a way to execute my string value as an object without using the eval function. Let me give some background so it makes more sense.
I am pulling the data from an object called tempArray. I have set

```
tempArray.values= {
"data": {
    "nonEditable": [
        {
            "name": "organization Name",
            "value": "Name of organization /"
        },
        {
            "name": "Description",
            "value": ""
        },
        ...
        ]}}
```

I am trying to make it so that I can dynamically get the extension for tempArray.values from another file called FieldLengths so that it is easy to change the locations where to pull data from in the future

```
const FieldLengths = (field) => {
var length, dataLocations
switch (field){
    case 'Department':
        length = 40
        dataLocations = ['data.nonEditable[0].name', 'data.editable[0].name' ]
        break
```

I am currently using a nested loop like this to try and achieve my goal

```
for(var k=0; k<tempArray.length; k++){
      tempArray[k].selectionValues = []
      for(var i=0; i<Fields.length; i++){
        dataLocations[i] = FieldProperties(Fields[i])[1]
        for(var j=0; j<dataLocations[i].length; j++){
          console.log(dataLocations[i][j]) //'data.nonEditable[0].name'
          let tempVal = 'tempArray[' + k '].values' + dataLocations[i][j]
          console.log(tempVal) //'tempArray[0].values.data.nonEditable[0].name'
          //I am trying to call that string value but don't know how without using eval()
        }
      }
    }
```

I am assuming that there is a way to do this without eval so any help would be appreciated. Thanks ahead of time